# integrals involving minimum function {a,1-a,b,1-b}

Tags: calculus, integration

I could not compute this integral. please help out! $0\le a,b \le 1$

$$f(a) = \int_0^1 \min{(a,1-a,b,1-b)}db$$

Comment: Do you mean $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\min\{a,1-a,b,1-b\}\,\mathrm da\,\mathrm db?$$ That would be the volume of a quadratic pyramid with base area $1$ and height $\frac12$.

Comment: no. just a SINGLE integral from 0 to 1. and db

Comment: Lt $c=\min\{a,1-a\}$ and consider $\int_0^c$, $\int_{c}^{1-c}$, $\int_{1-c}^1$ separately (in each of these cases the min is readily simplified)

Comment: could you please be more clear? i got stuck on this integral for nearly a day. i would really appreciate if you can help me to walk through. is the result of this integral a(1-a)?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the integrand as

$$\frac12 \min{\left[\min{(a,1-a)},\min{(b,1-b)} \right]}$$

which is the same as

$$\frac12 \min{\left[1-2\left|a-\frac12\right|, 1-2\left|b-\frac12\right|\right]}$$

You get the insight you need by drawing a picture.  When $a \in [0,1/2)$, we have

$$\min{\left[1-2\left|a-\frac12\right|, 1-2\left|b-\frac12\right|\right]} = \begin{cases} \\1-2\left|b-\frac12\right| & b \in [0,a)\\1-2\left|a-\frac12\right| & b \in [a,1-a) \\ 1-2\left|b-\frac12\right| & b \in [1-a,1] \end{cases}$$

so that the integral for $a \in (0,1/2)$ is

$$\frac12 \int_0^a db \, \left [ 1-2\left|b-\frac12\right|\right] + \frac12 \int_a^{1-a} db \,\left [ 1-2\left|a-\frac12\right|\right] + \frac12 \int_{1-a}^1 db \, \left [ 1-2\left|b-\frac12\right|\right] $$

To get the integral for $a \in (1/2,1)$, just substitute $a \leftarrow 1-a$ in the above integrals.

**ADDENDUM**

To see how this gets evaluated, let's look at the case $a \lt 1/2$ again.  The integrals become

$$\begin{align}\frac12 \int_0^a db \, 2 b +  \frac12 \int_a^{1-a} db \, 2 a + \frac12 \int_{1-a}^1 db \, (2-2 b)  &= \frac12 a^2 + a (1-2 a) + a - \frac12 [1-(1-a)^2] \\ &= a - a^2\end{align}$$

Comment: @ Ron Gordon: Wolfram Alpha gives a result of a(1-a). do you get the same thing? i still mess it up

Comment: @LindaLee: sorry for the delay; I had forgot a factor of $1/2$.  Now, yes, I do agree with WA.

Comment: @ Ron Gordon: could you show it here? i know it's a bit messy but i really mess up everything. thanks

Comment: @LindaLee: done, although I leave it to you to show it for $a > 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum of linear functions is piecewise linear.

If $b\le \min\{a,1-a\}$ (i.e. $b\le a$ and $b\le 1-a$), then of course $b\le \frac12$ (because $2b=b+b\le a+(1-a)=1$) and hence $b\le 1-b$, so we find 
$$ \min\{a,1-a,b,1-b\}=b\qquad\text{if }b\le\min\{a,1-a\}.$$
Similarly, we find
$$ \min\{a,1-a,b,1-b\}=1-b\qquad\text{if }b\ge\max\{a,1-a\}.$$
On the other hand, if $\min\{a,1-a\}\le b\le \max\{a,1-a\}$, then also  $\min\{a,1-a\}\le 1-b\le \max\{a,1-a\}$, hence 
$$ \min\{a,1-a,b,1-b\}=\min\{a,1-a\}\qquad\text{if }\min\{a,1-a\}\le b\le\max\{a,1-a\}.$$
Thus the graph of the function $b\mapsto \min\{a,1-a,b,1-b\}$ looks like a trapezoid with height $h=\min\{a,1-a\}$, lower base $w_1=1$, and upper base length $w_2=\max\{a,1-a\}-\min\{a,1-a\}$. 
That is, if $a\le 1-a$, then the height is $a$ and the upper base length is $(1-a)-a=1-2a$; and if $a\ge1-a$, the height is $1-a$ and the upper base length is $a-(1-a)=2a-1$. As the area is $A=\frac{h(w_1+w_2)}{2}$, we obtain
$$A=\frac{a\cdot((1-2a)+1)}{2}=a(1-a)\qquad\text{and}\qquad A=\frac{(1-a)\cdot((2a-1)+1)}{2}=a(1-a),$$
respectively. This area is also the integral in question.